# Getting a bind position from a bind name in OCI

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

When using `OCIStmtPrepare()` and `OCIBindByName()`, is there a way to do the bind by name, then get the position of that bind as an `int`? `OCIStmtGetBindInfo()` doesn't seem to do it. Thanks!

Comment: You can repeat a named variable multiple times in a statement and set it for all of them with a single `OCIBindByName()` call. So that may represent multiple positional parameters, so which of those positions would it use? See the [Overview of binding in OCI](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci05bnd.htm#i436225)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be an easy way to do it. I tried using the undocumented (as in I couldn't find it in the help docs but it is in the oci.h header) `OCI_ATTR_HANDLE_POSITION` using `OCIAttrGet()` on the bind handle:

```
ub4 bpos = 0;
OCIBind *bindp;
OCIAttrGet(bindp, OCI_HTYPE_BIND, &bpos, 0, OCI_ATTR_HANDLE_POSITION, errhp);
```

Unfortunately, that seems to work for bind handles that you bound positionally, but return 0 for any you bound by name.

So it seems like you would have to use the [`OCIStmtGetBindInfo()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14250/oci15rel003.htm#sthref2656) call to have it fill an array of bind variable names then iterate through it to find the position(s) for each named bind, either by comparing the bind name to the values in the bind variable names array (the values of which will be uppercased):

```
sb4 found = 0;
text* bvns[100];
ub1 bvnls[100];
text* invs[100];
ub1 invls[100];
ub1 dupls[100];
OCIBind* bhnds[100];
OCIStmtGetBindInfo(stmthp, errhp, (ub4)100, (ub4)1, &found, bvns, bvnls, invs, invls, dupls, bhnds);
for (unsigned int col = 0; col < found; col++)
{
    printf("%p is bound to name: %s", bhnds[col], bvns[col]);
}
```

One interesting thing to note about multiple placeholders in a statement is that it behaves differently if your statement is an anonymous block or not. That is:

```
insert into foo (bar, baz) values (:bar, :bar)
```

Will fill your `found` output variable with 2 (and the arrays with info for 2 binds), whereas:

```
begin insert into foo (bar, baz) values (:bar, :bar); end;
```

Will fill your `found` output variable with 1 (and the arrays with info for 1 bind).
Nonetheless, a single call to `OCIBindByName()` will bind both in either case.

Comment: I think you're right, there's no way to do it just within OCI. Thanks!